# Setting up resharper with specific coding standards

Tags: c#, coding-style, resharper, naming-conventions, resharper-10.0

I'm trying to set up resharper with certain coding standards but I can't find where to set them up.

Coding standards like the following:

Class/struct member variable will have a prefix: `m_CamelCase`

Const Class/struct member variable will have a prefix: `k_CamelCase=1`

Static Class/struct member variable will have a prefix: `s_CamelCase=1`

Readonly Class/struct member variable will have a prefix: `r_CamelCase=1`

Function parameters will have `i_` or `o_` or `io_` prefix depending on whether they're input, output or both. Is this even possible to automate?

Are these settings possible?

Here's the settings page to make it easier:

[image]

Comment: I didn't realise people were still using those prefixes for scope and parameter direction :/

Comment: It's enforced by my instructor... But, other being annoying to remember to implement, are they really bad? @DavidG

Comment: No bad per se, but it's really a hangover from older times when IDEs were not powerful enough to provide the information.

Comment: Please, for the love of god, don't do this. Tell your instructor he's wrong.

Comment: @IgalTabachnik it will fall on deaf ears, my instructor ego's is so high, he thinks he's literally batman and ironman and he beats terror with .Net applications...

Comment: Your CamelCase is actually PascalCase. See how useful camelCase is?